# How to access tuple items?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and am encountering a problem. I have a tuple as variable. When I'm running the following script to fetch the particular value, I get an error:

```
row = ('ip-172-17-11-22', 'i-050303gfredsgda', None, None, 'Linux Server', None, None)
for i in row:
    if i[4] ==  'Linux Server':
        print(i[2])
    else:
        print("no value")
```

Here's the error:

```
no value
no value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-data.py", line 4, in <module>
    if i[4] ==  'Linux Server':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: when you have `for i in row` you're iterating over each item in the tuple. the first value `i` would have is `'ip-172-17-11-22` and the next one would be the second element in the tuple, etc. when it gets to the third one, you're trying to do `i[2]` where `i` is set to None, which is causing the error

Comment: `print` is a good debug tool. You could temporarily add a `print(i)` at the top of the loop to see the value before trouble starts.

Comment: Can you also include expected results?

Comment: None is its own unique type in python. I'm not sure what the loop is attempting to accomplish, but `i` will be equal to a new (the next in the tuple) element on each iteration. Regardless of what you are trying to do, you are inevitably going to attempt to index (get the value of) None[4]. This is a TypeError.

Comment: You don’t need a `for` loop here, just access the specific indices of `row` that you want to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, what you'd like to do, is, in pseudo-code:

```
for element in row:
    if element = '...'
    print(element that is 2 indexes before)
```

and the problem is this "element that is 2 indexes before": you can't use a relative position based on the element you're on. The solution is to use `enumerate` so that you can get the element **and its index**:

```
row = ('ip-172-17-11-22', 'i-050303gfredsgda', None, None, 'Linux Server', None, None)
for i, item in enumerate(row):  # each iteration will return a tuple:(item index, item)
    if item ==  'Linux Server':
        print(row[i-2])
    else:
        print("no value")
```

Note: if 'Linux Server' is at position lower than 2, the `row[i-2]` may have unexpected results, since using negative indexes corresponds to counting backwards, from the end of the tuple (or list).

E.g.: in your example,

```
row[-1] --> None, 
row[-2] --> None, 
row[-3] -->'Linux Server',
etc.
```

So handling the cases where i-2 is negative could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
if row[4] == 'Linux Server':
    if row[2]:
        print(row[2])
    else:
        print("no value")
else:
    print("no value")
```

Comment: This still gives "No Value". I want to print value 2 ie ```'i-050303gfredsgda'```

Comment: @shailysharma, use `row[1]`